# Setting multi-line labels fully-justified in IB?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uilabel

This just seems like it should be so simple, since there is a setting to make a table fully-justified within IB. It just doesn't work most of the time, and is unpredictable when it *tries* to work. I cannot believe this is out in production.

***How are we expected to display a UILabel with full-justification in IB?***

I have read of the use of NSAttributedString to manage this in code, and that is easy enough, but many labels are static, with no need for manipulation within a loading event, and that just defeats the purpose of setting a label within IB, to a degree, other than basic layout, and even then you'd need to run the app to see what your screen looks like.

Hopefully i am just missing something basic here, but full-justification within UILabel is just wonky as hell.

Comment: what do you mean by `full-justification`, is it dynamic size according to text or something else? sorry if the question looks selly it just confused me.

Comment: I refer to the 4th setting within IB, or in code referred to NSTextAlignmentJustified.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: At this stage, i am inclined to think UILabels just don't show fully-justified text. I set via attributed text a test label, programatically, and the resultant display was just as incorrect as the IB setting, so it seems to be baked incorrectly. Oh well, left and centering it will be for now. I hope i am just wrong in this. No answers over at the apple dev forums either.